# How come "basketball" is common noun but "Spelling Bee" is proper noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns

I started reading "Primary School English Grammar & Composition by Wren & Martin" to improve my grammar.

The book explains:

- *A Common Noun is the name given in common to every person or thing of the same class or kind; such as, man, woman, boy, girl, town, country, book, desk.*
- *A Proper Noun is the special name of a particular person or place; such as, Abdul, Rama, Sita, Shirin, Mumbai, India.*

So as an exercise we need to identify which are common and proper nouns in below sentences.

1. We will play basketball at the park.
2. The Spelling Bee is an amazing championship.

The answer to the above questions given by the authors is that **basketball is common noun** and **Spelling Bee is proper noun**.

I'm confused how is **Spelling Bee** a proper noun? Isn't it also a competition/game like **basketball**?

**Research (my understanding):**

Basketball is a game which has many characteristics, there can be many basketball games but same goes for Spelling Bee competition.
It's just like Basketball which has some characteristics and there can be many Spelling Bee competitions.

So how come Basketball is a common noun in first sentence and Spelling Bee is proper noun in second sentence?

I'm confused. If *Spelling Bee* is a proper noun because it's a specific characteristic of a competition than doesn't it make *Basketball* a proper noun too?

**Note: screenshots from the text book and Key book**
[image: screenshots from the text book and Key book]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147112/discussion-on-question-by-mysterious-jack-how-come-basketball-is-common-noun-b); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The open compound noun << spelling bee >> is a common  noun and lowercased (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_bee)).  Quite often, **particular** venues, events, persons and the like are capitalised. An opera house / the Opera House, Buxton // a carnival / Carnival // a queen / the Queen. So 'The spelling bee competition is held among all public primary and secondary school in Lagos' but 'What are the rules of the Spelling Bee game?' and 'The Spelling Bee is a literacy programme that teaches ... children' etc. Highlight quotes as well as capitalisation could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the fact that when the official spelling competition, **[National Spelling Bee](https://spellingbee.com/about#:%7E:text=The%20National%20Spelling%20Bee%20began,11%20million%20students%20each%20year)**, was first held in 1925, it was the name of a nationwide competition but the actual spelling game, "**[spelling bee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_bee)**", likely predated 1850.

This explains why an *annual* nationwide-competition can be capitalised but a game or sport, however well-known, is not. In other words, Wren & Martin are perfectly correct.

> A ***spelling bee*** is a competition in which contestants are asked to spell a broad selection of words, usually with a varying degree of difficulty. To compete, contestants must memorize the spellings of words as written in dictionaries, and recite them accordingly.

The *Wikipedia* article continues (note the capitalization in bold)

> Spelling bees became widespread across the United States during the 1800s, as a way to motivate students to learn standardized spelling. These **spelling bees** were usually held within individual schools and towns, and were not nationally organized. In 1908, the NEA held what it called the "first national spelling bee" at its convention in Cleveland. Marie Bolden, a black girl from Cleveland, was named champion.
>
> The annual **United States National Spelling Bee** was started in 1925 by The Courier-Journal, the newspaper of Louisville, Kentucky. The winner was Frank Neuhauser, who won the 1st **National Spelling Bee** in Washington, D.C. in 1925 at the age of eleven.

Worth noting that the series of English grammar books by Wren & Martin were first published in 1935 and were originally intended for the children of British officers deployed in India. The books; *Elementary English Grammar*, *A First Book of English Grammar and Composition*, *High School English Grammar and Composition* and *A Final Course of Grammar & Composition* became hugely popular and continue to be adopted by Indian and Pakistani schools  long after [British India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidencies_and_provinces_of_British_India)  was partitioned into India, Pakistan and Bangladesh in 1947. It goes without saying that the series of books have since been updated.

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps they consider that the question is better suited to say ELL ... or they feel this has been said before and think that finding a duplicate would take excessive time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or they somehow resent what is the most obvious answer and that they didn't think of it.

Comment: @Lambie The 'obvious' of it was already given in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelling%20bee&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).

The capitalisation of all nouns was quite common up to about the end of the 18th century. The idea of capitalising only proper nouns developed after that (probably as a result of saving time when typesetting a book.)

You will note that spelling bees started in the late 19th century when there was still some tendency to capitalise common nouns and anything that was **or looked like** a name: especially a new invention.

(If you look through the examples, you will also see a hyphenated version.)

Spelling Bee and spelling bee both apparently appear as popular choices with the lowercase being currently much more popuar. But, you will also note, the capitalised version is usually an example of the phrase used in a title - and titles are capitalised.

The capitalisation of the names of games (except commerically produced games) is dying out.

The same is true of basketball - it was originally capitalised but common use has removed the capitalisation - when Spelling Bee gets enough use, it will lose the uppercase - except in titles.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that "Spelling Bee", when used as a common (not proper) noun, is sometimes capitalized due to a holdover effect from the 18th century. Do you have any solid evidence of that? You also say that "when Spelling Bee gets enough use, it will lose the uppercase", but your ngram actually suggests that the uppercase version is increasing, not decreasing, in frequency.

Comment: What I am saying is that S/spelling B/bee is a 19th c. phrase that is in transit between the capitalisation (i) that was generally applied to nouns; (ii) that is generally applied to proper nouns/names; and (iii) that appears in titles, (iv) that does not appear in basketball. The tendency in language is that use towards simplicity and so the final iteration should be lowercase. The Ngram (for what it's worth) shows a decline in capitalisation that is even greater when titles are removed. This would lead to lowercase for the majority of contexts.

Comment: a book and... what? The suspense is killing me ;-)

Comment: I agree that "Spelling Bee" might retain some vestigial capitalization due to that older practice, but without specific evidence, I think that it's speculation. As for the ngram, I'm clicking on your link and not making any changes, and it shows that "Spelling Bee" increased from 0.0000007510% in 1971 to 0.0000032660% in 2018, a more-than-fourfold increase over that time. (Are you getting those numbers, too? Perhaps Google is showing us different results.)

Comment: You will note that the gradients of the graph follow each other. If you increase the smoothing to 40, you will note that the gradient of the graph for uppercase is less than the lowercase - the frequency of use of the phrase is increasing in both forms but the gap is widening in favour of lowercase. You can do a similar graph for "football" and "baseball." Also, bear in mind book titles that skew the results.

Comment: A bee is a gathering of people, usually neighbors,  for a task, usually to help a particular person or family. Look it up (M-W). The Ngram viewer quotes a 1875 entry from an Indiana University magazine, noting that there are quilting bees, raising bees (e.g., of a barn), and the education-oriented spelling bee.

Comment: A bee is thus a common noun, as is spelling bee, whether capitalized here and there or not.